# Scala eval function that gets a String with variables

Tags: scala, eval, string-interpolation, scala-reflect

I want to be able to evaluate the expression that returns from `func`.
The problem is that the expression includes the variable `a`, which is not familiar in the scope of `func` but is familiar in the scope of `playground`.

I want to be able to send the String: `s"$a + 1"` when `$` is not an operator and `s` is a part of the String. I saw that `$$` should solve the problem with the `$`, but then the char `s` is not a part of the String, and the `eval` function needs an expression with the pattern of `s""`.

```
object playground extends App{
  val a = 5.5
  val expression = func()
  val str: String = expression
  val tb = currentMirror.mkToolBox()
  val x = tb.eval(tb.parse(str)).toString
  print(x)
}

object second {
  def func(): String = {
    s"$a + 1"
  }
}
```

Thanks for any help :)

Answer (score 0):

> expression includes the variable `a`, which is not familiar in the scope of `func` but is familiar in the scope of `playground`.

Try to fully qualify the variable

```
def func(): String =
  s"${playground.a} + 1"
```

or use import

```
def func(): String =
  s"import playground._; $a + 1"
```

```
def func(): String =
  s"""
    import playground._
    $a + 1
  """
```

or add a parameter to the function

```
def func(a: Double): String =
  s"$a + 1"
```

```
val a = 5.5
val expression = func(a)
```

> `s"$a + 1"` when `$` is not an operator and `s` is a part of the String. I
> saw that `$$` should solve the problem with the `$`, but then the char `s`
> is not a part of the String

I'm not sure what you're after. Try to provide some inputs and desired outputs to make it clear.

`"$a + 1"` is just a String (with a dollar sign), `s"$a + 1"` is a String where a variable `a` from current scope is substituted (after `.toString`).

Yes, you can escape `$` inside `s"..."` as `$$`. So `s"$$a + 1"` is the same as just `"$a + 1"` (without prefix `s`).

I don't understand what *"`s` is a part of the String"*, *"but then the char `s` is not a part of the String"* mean.

> and the `eval` function needs an expression
> with the pattern of `s""`.

Why? `tb.parse` (or `q"..."`) accepts arbitrary String. `tb.eval` accepts arbitrary Tree.

---

I guess I got it. It seems you are expecting `func()` to *expand* into `s"$a + 1"` at a call site. Then `s"$a + 1"` should be not a String but a Tree itself (`s"$a + 1"` should be not a String `s""" s"$$a + 1" """` but a piece of code) and `func()` should be a [macro](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/macros/overview.html).

```
import scala.language.experimental.macros
import scala.reflect.macros.blackbox

object second {
  def func(): String = macro funcImpl

  def funcImpl(c: blackbox.Context)(): c.Tree = {
    import c.universe._
    q""" s"$$a + 1" """
  }
}
```

```
// in a different subproject

import second.func
import scala.reflect.runtime.currentMirror
import scala.tools.reflect.ToolBox

object playground extends App {
  val a = 5.5
  val expression = func()
  val str: String = expression
  val tb = currentMirror.mkToolBox()
  val x = tb.eval(tb.parse(str)).toString
  print(x) // 6.5
}
```

But using macros (and mixing them with runtime compilation via Toolbox) in your case seems an overkill, you should prefer easier options from the above.